# Python type annotation for sequences of strings, but not for strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Is there a Python type hint that matches lists, tuples and possibly other sequential types, but does not match strings?

The issue is that strings are at the same time sequences of strings of length 1 (e.g. individual characters), so they technically match the `Sequence[str]`, but providing a string to a function expecting a list of strings is an error in maybe 100% cases.

Is there a way to exclude strings from type annotation to make it something similar to non-existent `And[Sequence[str], Not[str]]`?

As for the purpose, I would like to annotate this function:

```
PathType = Union[str, os.PathLike]
def escape_cmdline(argv: Union[List[PathType], Tuple[PathType]]) -> str: ...
```

But existing signature looks bloated to me, and does not cover any custom types that are list and tuple compatible. Is there any better way?

Comment: I think that this question might receive more attention when you reword it into something more generic like "Type annotation for a `Sequence` which is not `str` or `bytes`" or something like that.

Comment: What about the plethora of other bytes-like objects in Python? `bytearray`, `memoryview`, `mmap.mmap`, various `array.array` types, `numpy` types, etc. It's not easy to draw a fine distinction here. `str` is basically unique on Py3, but bytes-like types are a dime a dozen.

Comment: Side-note: Why are you escaping command line paths? `subprocess` takes sequences of arguments and invokes them without the need for escaping when you're not using `shell=True`. Just making you you're not solving the wrong problem.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, oh, escaping is not because I am invoking subprocesses myself — this is because this function is used when generating shell scripts, that are to be invoked later, and not even by me.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, important detail is that majority of the types you have mentioned are not sequences of strings or bytes. Unfortunately, string is also a sequence of strings of the length 1, so it's both a "value" and "sequence". I'd like to somehow exclude strings from the annotation.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your problem is that `str` is already a sequence of characters but the character is not an existing type *per se* in python and you’re unable to restrict a sequence of characters to be only characters rather than a sequence of strings?

Comment: @misanthrope, almost. I want to limit my sequence to be only sequence of strings, but exclude _just strings_, which also happen to be sequences of chars (e.g. 1-char strings). So, I don't want strings to pass the test for "sequence of strings".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparently, this is not possible with type hints. PEP 484 can not distinguish between `Sequence[str]`, `Iterable[str]` and `str` according to Guido van Rossum.

Source: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1965 and https://github.com/python/typing/issues/256

Comment: Wonder what the point in the type annotations is if it can't help with something as basic as this.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't find anything about the type *exclusion* or the type *negation*, seems like it's not supported in current version of Python 3. So the only distinctive feature of strings that crossed my mind is that **strings are immutable**. Maybe it'll help:

```
from typing import Union
from collections.abc import MutableSequence


MySequenceType = Union[MutableSequence, tuple, set]
def foo(a: MySequenceType):
    pass

foo(["09485", "kfjg", "kfjg"]) # passed
foo(("09485", "kfjg", "kfjg")) # passed
foo({"09485", "kfjg", "kfjg"}) # passed
foo("qwerty") # not passed
```

Comment: Tuples are immutable as well.

Comment: Yeah, @N M, I agree. That's why the `tuple` type and also `set` type are dealt with separately in the code above (by the way, `set` is not even a `Sequence`). This is lame and is not the direct answer to the question asked but maybe it will help somebody to answer better.

Answer (score 2):

I might not fully understand your questions but to me it looks like you're in search for the following shortcut:

```
for object in data:
    if not isinstance(object, type):
        your code functions + list...
        .... etc.
```

wherease type is `str` and `object` an variable from your **raw data** provided through a `list` or `tuple` of items. If I misunderstood your question deepening your question with more details may perhaps help? Or was the above answer enough to get you going? Then a little feedback wound be nice ;-)

Answer (score 1):

### Somewhat, in some circumstances and if you use Mypy

There is actually one way: Use an `@overload` with `Never` as the return type.

```py
from typing import overload, Never
from collections.abc import Iterable  # Or Sequence

@overload
def first(v: str) -> Never:
    ...

@overload
def first(v: Iterable[str]) -> str:
    ...

def first(v: Iterable[str]) -> str:
    return next(iter(v))
```

This is not sufficient, however. Mypy will still [consider the following as fine](https://%20https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=990d3757cc68602a06c50169db621962):

```py
first(['foo'])  # Fine
first('foo')  # Anything after this line is simply ignored.

a = 'bar'
reveal_type(a)  # Silently emit nothing.
```

The `--warn-unreachable` flag allows you to configure this behaviour. With it, Mypy [will raise an error](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict%2Cwarn-unreachable&mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=ecafa80fe4f57abe4c85c85d8808825d) saying the line is unreachable:

```py
first(['foo'])  # Fine
first('foo')  # Still no error, however.

a = 'bar'  # error: Statement is unreachable
```

On the other hand, while raising no errors, Pylance, which uses Pyright under the hood, will fade unreachable code out:

[image: Code is unreachable (Pylance)]

It only does so for explicitly type-hinted code though:

[image: def g() -> NoReturn: return first(v='foo') / g() / b = 'bar']