# Python type hint for Iterable[str] that isn't str

Tags: python, types, type-hinting

In Python, is there a way to distinguish between strings and other iterables of strings?

A `str` is valid as an `Iterable[str]` type, but that may not be the correct input for a function. For example, in this trivial example that is intended to operate on sequences of filenames:

```
from typing import Iterable

def operate_on_files(file_paths: Iterable[str]) -> None:
    for path in file_paths:
        ...
```

Passing in a single filename would produce the wrong result but would not be caught by type checking. I know that I can check for string or byte types at runtime, but I want to know if it's possible to catch silly mistakes like that with a type-checking tool.

I've looked over the `collections.abc` module and there doesn't seem to be any abc that would include typical iterables (e.g. lists, tuples) but exclude strings. Similarly, for the `typing` module, there doesn't seem to be a type for iterables that don't include strings.

Comment: If you are using type hinting, then you can use a third-party library to do type-based multiple dispatch, and overload the version for `str` to raise an exception. Or you can explicitly type-check at runtime. I don't know of any purely static check for this, though, even with mypy.

Comment: Discussed by mypy maintainers [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5090). 

Not the answer you are after but how about [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=316762a6b22da6bf9ae99fadfb295aae)

Comment: So I'm not allowed to name my files "a", "b" and "c" and call your function with "abc"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python type annotation for sequences of strings, but not for strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912374/python-type-annotation-for-sequences-of-strings-but-not-for-strings)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### As of March 2022, the answer is **no**.

This issue has been discussed since at least July 2016. On a proposal to distinguish between `str` and `Iterable[str]`, [Guido van Rossum](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/256) writes:

> Since `str` *is* a valid iterable of `str` this is tricky. Various proposals have been made but they don't fit easily in the type system.

**You'll need to list out all of the types that you want your functions to accept explicitly**, using `Union` (pre-3.10) or `|` (3.10 and higher).

e.g. For pre-3.10, use:

```py
from typing import Union
## Heading ##
def operate_on_files(file_paths: Union[TypeOneName, TypeTwoName, etc.]) -> None:
    for path in file_paths:
        ...
```

For 3.10 and higher, use:

```py
## Heading ##
def operate_on_files(file_paths: TypeOneName | TypeTwoName | etc.) -> None:
    for path in file_paths:
        ...
```

If you happen to be using Pytype, [it will not treat `str` as an `Iterable[str]`](https://github.com/google/pytype/blob/main/docs/faq.md#why-doesnt-str-match-against-string-iterables) (as pointed out by [Kelly Bundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671057/kelly-bundy)). But, this behavior is typechecker-specific, and isn't widely supported in other typecheckers.

Comment: But as of August 2021, pytype does it (found on the page you linked to).

Comment: I added it to the original answer, but as far as I'm aware this behavior isn't supported in other typecheckers.

Answer (score 0):

`pytype` (the type checker from Google) by default treat `str` as non-iterable and will raise error if you pass a `str` to a function expecting `Iterable[str]`. If you do need to handle a `str` as `Iterable[str]` you'll have to pass `iter(s)`.

See https://google.github.io/pytype/faq.html#why-doesnt-str-match-against-string-iterables