# Is string a valid type for annotation Sequence[Sequence[str]]?

Tags: python, string, python-typing

This is a typical example of a value that can be annotated by `Sequence[Sequence[str]]`:

```py
[
    ['This', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'tokenized', 'sentence', '.'],
    ['And', 'this', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'one', '.'],
]
```

I have learned that [string is a valid type for annotation `Sequence[str]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912374/python-type-annotation-for-sequences-of-strings-but-not-for-strings), since, loosely speaking, *strings are sequences of strings* in the Python world. **Does that work recursively?** Is string also a valid type for annotation `Sequence[Sequence[str]]` etc.?

I'd say *yes*, following the Python logic, but I'd say *no*, following the common sense. And I don't know how to properly test it.

Comment: Since Python itself doesn't do anything with annotations, this question must be answered by whatever tool is interpreting the annotation…

Comment: PyCharm says that `str` is not a valid type annotation for `Sequence[Sequence[str]]`, just checked on my environment. However, PyCharm also says it's not valid for `Sequence[str]`

Comment: @grey_ranger Are you sure? The code `foo: Sequence[str] = 'foo'` does not (and should not) show any warning to me.

Comment: Common sense doesn't deal well with infinities :)

Comment: @Jeyekomon the code doesn't give any error (and runs fine), but my version of PyCharm shows a linting type hint that the input type to the function is wrong. I used `def func(foo: Sequence[str])` followed by `func('foo')`. The PyCharm hint shows up on the function call, not the definition.

Comment: @grey_ranger That behaviour is not spec-compliant, given that [`str` inherits from `Sequence[str]`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/a2095002e446bd0e20f8a469a14e271cd6cc6ad9/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L433), although I could see where its developers are coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a definition of sequence in Python's [glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence):

**sequence**

> An iterable which supports efficient element access using
> integer indices via the `__getitem__()` special method and defines a
> `__len__()` method that returns the length of the sequence. Some built-in sequence types are `list`, `str`, `tuple`, and `bytes`. Note that
> dict also supports `__getitem__()` and `__len__()`, but is considered a
> mapping rather than a sequence because the lookups use arbitrary
> immutable keys rather than integers.

`str` of course meets of all the above requirements, but is also self recursive, meaning its `__getitem__()` returns an instance of itself. No matter how deep we try to go, elements of str sequence will be str sequences themselves. As evident by the comments, different tools may treat it differently, but going purely by definitions, `str` is an infinitely nested sequence of sequences.

This may seem unintuitive, but that is pretty much parallel to:

```
s = "python"
print(s[1][0][0][0])
```

If you don't expect this to fail, then `Sequence[Sequence[str]]` shouldn't fail either.

Comment: The `'python'[1][0][0]` is a very good point. I've never realized that string is an infinitely nested sequence of sequences.

Comment: It's the reason people who try to write functions that distinguish between scalars and iterables have so much trouble with strings. Is `"foo"` a single value or an iterable that produces `"f"`, `"o"`, and `"o"`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an annotation like `a: Sequence[Sequence[str]] = ""` is valid. This is a consequence of how `str` is represented in the typing system. From [typeshed's definition of `str`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/78b7dc61676ff332622402437881a651249c6108/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L433):

```py
class str(Sequence[str]):
    ...
```

You can try it yourself with your own user-defined type, like so (demo: [mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=strict&gist=dfcc75d42fbb047cb64dbec70bede966), [Pyright Playground](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBAxmA28CmMAuBLMA7AzgOgEMAjGKdCABzBFSgGUkBHAVySxiQFgAoHmeAjhxQAggAoGLNhwDaAIhFyAugEoAXFDxaePAhsmt2SGQenGRSpVAC8osSp4gkANyQF4AfVQBPCkjEEMgAMSjIAjKEATKEAzKEALKEArKpAA)):

```py
from collections.abc import Sequence

class A(Sequence["A"]): ...
```

```
>>> a: Sequence[Sequence[A]] = A()
>>> reveal_type(a[0][1][2][3][4][5])  # revealed type is "A"
```

---

P.S. - In your linked question ([Python type annotation for sequences of strings, but not for strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912374/python-type-annotation-for-sequences-of-strings-but-not-for-strings)), nobody there has posted a solution. A sequence of `str` but not `str` is in fact doable (see the [useful_types](https://github.com/hauntsaninja/useful_types) project's [`SequenceNotStr`](https://github.com/hauntsaninja/useful_types/blob/951d36b2aaaee6ab9fa1efcb8c4f1e2733247ff5/useful_types/__init__.py#L285-L295)), but has some [remaining issues](https://github.com/hauntsaninja/useful_types/issues/21).